# Сохранение картинки из интернета в каталог Saved Pictures

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windowsphone, winrt

Всем привет. Пишу приложение для Windows Phone 8.1. Нужно сохранить изображение на телефон. Использую данный код, но изображение а папке фото не появляется. Через "проводник" на компьютере файл есть, но он не открывается как изображение. 
В чем проблема, посоветуйте может какой другой вариант. 
Спасибо

```
StorageFolder picsFolder = KnownFolders.SavedPictures;
StorageFile file = await picsFolder.CreateFileAsync("Allah.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

string url = content.image;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

byte[] responseBytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);

var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

using (var outputStream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
{
    DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(outputStream);
    writer.WriteBytes(responseBytes);
    writer.StoreAsync();
    outputStream.FlushAsync();
}
MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Done");
dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: Вы не закрываете внешний поток `stream`. Попробуйте обернуть его в `using`.

Comment: Плюс вызовы `StoreAsync()` и `FlushAsync()` тоже нужно await'ить.

Comment: Изображения Аллаха запрещены в Исламе, я уверен, что картинка поэтому не сохраняется.

Comment: @andreycha: Это, кстати, наверняка и есть проблема. Запись запускается, и не дожидаясь окончания закрывается поток.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что вы не ожидаете завершения методов `StoreAsync()` и `FlushAsync()`. Без их ожидания ваш метод завершается, но сохраненной картинки еще может не быть. Также если во время выполнения этих методов происходит ошибка, вы об этом не узнаёте!

Плюс еще несколько советов:

1. Оберните использование `stream` в `using`. Т.о. использованные
   ресурсы будут правильным образом закрываться, даже в случае ошибки.
2. В библиотечном (не UI) коде используйте ConfigureAwait(false). Т.о.
   текущий контекст исполнения не захватывается, что позволяет избежать
   возможных дедлоков, а также сэкономить на переключениях.

Итого:

```
using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite).ConfigureAwait(false))
using (var outputStream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
{
    DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(outputStream);
    writer.WriteBytes(responseBytes);
    await writer.StoreAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    await outputStream.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```